# Sequence animation in angular

Tags: angular, animation

i would like the create a simple collapse animation with 3 states. I'm using Angular 7.2.2

> closed -> animating -> open
>
> open -> animating -> closed

I trying to use [sequence](https://angular.io/api/animations/sequence) but I'm not able to do it.
This is my original code.

```
export const collapseAnimation = trigger('collapse', [
  state('open', style({
   opacity: '1',
   display: 'block',
  })),
  state('closed',   style({
    height: '0',
    overflow : 'hidden'
   })),
  state('none',   style({
   opacity: '1'
   })),

 transition('closed => open', animate('200ms ease-in')),
 transition('open => closed', animate('200ms ease-out'))
]);
```

But I want to do something like this (create some inline style between state closed and state open or between open and closed:

```
   transition('closed => open', 
   sequence(
     [animate('2000ms', style ({background: 'green',overflow : 'hidden'})),
     animate('2000ms ease-in', style ({ opacity: '1',display: 'block'}))]
     )),
   transition('open => closed', 
   sequence(
     [style({ background: 'green',overflow : 'hidden'}),animate('2000ms ease-out')]
     ))
```

The style background: green is an example just to see if it working, but when I run the code the sequence only apply the time(2000ms) but the style is null.

[**Example on stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vygub?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Thank you everyone.

Comment: you haven't added default style style({ ... })), in your sequence array

Comment: Thank you. I`m trying this, but is still not working. 

   transition('closed => open', 
     sequence(
       [style ({background: 'yellow',overflow : 'hidden'}),
        animate('2000ms', style ({background: 'green',overflow : 'hidden'}))]
       ))

Comment: can you create stackblitz for this.

Comment: Thank you this is more or less the code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vygub